# Dagger and Room, not creating DaggerTestAppComoponent.create()

Tags: android, android-espresso, dagger-2

I'm trying to run an end-to-end test on an app that uses Dagger and Room, When I run the app Dagger isn't able to generate `DaggerTestAppComponent.create()`.

I've been following the [Dagger codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-dagger#13) to implement the Dagger into the tests.

Here's a link to the repository on Github. https://github.com/Shawn-Nichol/EndToEnd

`Step 1. Custom Test Runner`
User a custom test runner to use a different application class.

```
class MyCustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MyTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

`Step 2 add to app build gradle.` 
The custom test runner is specified in the app build Gradle.

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.endtoend.dagger.MyCustomTestRunner"
```

`Step 3 load Modules`
`TestAppComponent`, Graph for AndroidTest scope set.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [TestSaveDataStorageModule::class, RoomModule::class, DispatchersModule::class])
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }
}
```

`Step 4 Add dependencies`
In order to generate `DaggerTestAppComponent` The `kapt` needs to act on the `androidTest` source set.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
}
```

`step 5 update application`
MyApplication

```
open class MyApplication : Application() {
    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        initializeComponent()
    }
    open fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

`Step 6`
TestApplication

```
class TestApplication : MyApplication() {

    override fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerTestAppComponent.create()
    }
}
```

After completing these steps, I run a test so Dagger can generate the `DaggerTestAppComponent` but it doesn't generate a `DaggerTestAppComponent.create()` creating an unresolved reference in the code.

`DaggerTestAppComponent`

```
@SuppressWarnings({
    "unchecked",
    "rawtypes"
})
public final class DaggerTestAppComponent implements TestAppComponent {
  private Provider<MyRepository> myRepositoryProvider;

  private Provider<Context> contextProvider;

  private Provider<MyDatabase> provideDatabaseProvider;

  private Provider<ItemDao> provideDaoProvider;

  private Provider<RoomRepository> roomRepositoryProvider;

  private Provider<CoroutineDispatcher> providesIoDispatcherProvider;

  private Provider<MainViewModel> mainViewModelProvider;

  private DaggerTestAppComponent(DispatchersModule dispatchersModuleParam, Context contextParam) {

    initialize(dispatchersModuleParam, contextParam);
  }

  public static TestAppComponent.Factory factory() {
    return new Factory();
  }

  private MyAdapter myAdapter() {
    return new MyAdapter(mainViewModelProvider.get());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initialize(final DispatchersModule dispatchersModuleParam,
      final Context contextParam) {
    this.myRepositoryProvider = MyRepository_Factory.create((Provider) FakeSaveData_Factory.create());
    this.contextProvider = InstanceFactory.create(contextParam);
    this.provideDatabaseProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(RoomModule_Companion_ProvideDatabaseFactory.create(contextProvider));
    this.provideDaoProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(RoomModule_Companion_ProvideDaoFactory.create(provideDatabaseProvider));
    this.roomRepositoryProvider = RoomRepository_Factory.create(provideDaoProvider);
    this.providesIoDispatcherProvider = DispatchersModule_ProvidesIoDispatcherFactory.create(dispatchersModuleParam);
    this.mainViewModelProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(MainViewModel_Factory.create(myRepositoryProvider, roomRepositoryProvider, providesIoDispatcherProvider));
  }

  @Override
  public void inject(MainActivity arg0) {
    injectMainActivity(arg0);
  }

  @Override
  public void inject(ListFragment arg0) {
    injectListFragment(arg0);
  }

  private MainActivity injectMainActivity(MainActivity instance) {
    MainActivity_MembersInjector.injectViewModel(instance, mainViewModelProvider.get());
    return instance;
  }

  private ListFragment injectListFragment(ListFragment instance) {
    ListFragment_MembersInjector.injectRvAdapter(instance, myAdapter());
    return instance;
  }

  private static final class Factory implements TestAppComponent.Factory {
    @Override
    public TestAppComponent create(Context context) {
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(context);
      return new DaggerTestAppComponent(new DispatchersModule(), context);
    }
  }
}
```

If I don't have a room installed in the app Dagger will generate `DaggerTestAppComponent.create()`. It's once setup room Dagger stops generating `DaggerTestAppComponent.create()`.

Dagger dependencies

```
    def dagger_version = "2.33"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```

Build output

```
> Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin FAILED
e: C:\Android\TestingEx\EndToEnd\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\endtoend\TestApplication.kt: (14, 39): Unresolved reference: create
```

Comment: do you have error during the build ?

Comment: @Ruokki its an unresolved reference to `DaggerTestAppComponent.create()`.  Which should be generated when `DaggerTestAppcomponeont` is generated.

Comment: Yes but in most of the case when DaggerXXXComponent class didn't appear you will have an error log in the build who explain what is wrong with your dagger component (Circular reference/ not provided dependency/ etc )

Comment: @Ruokki, I've included the build output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be two problems with your Dagger AndroidTest setup.

The TestApplication is calling a non existent function.

> class TestApplication : MyApplication() {
>
> ```
> override fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
>     return DaggerTestAppComponent.create()
> } }
> ```

You want to return `DaggerTestAppComponent.factory().create()`, you can see it at the bottom of the generated `DaggerTestAppComponent` file.

```
return DaggerTestAppComponent.factory().create(this)
```

Number two
In the TestAppComponent the `create()` function returns the dagger AppComponent graph, you'll want to change that so it returns the TestAppComponent graph.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    TestSaveDataStorageModule::class,
    RoomModule::class
])
interface TestAppComponent : AppComponent {


    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): TestAppComponent
    }
}
```